# Difference between loading and attaching in [R]

Tags: r

In RStudio, when I check and uncheck a package, I see the following commands.

```
library("ggplot2", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
detach("package:ggplot2", unload=TRUE)
```

Can someone explain what is unload=TRUE does?

Conceptually is there a difference between loading/unloading vs attaching/detaching?

[image: RStudio Attaching and Loading of packages]

Comment: I believe the help for [?detach](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/detach.html) explains it all: `detach()` "remove[s an object] from the search() path of available R objects", and the argument `unload = TRUE` "attempt[s] to unload the namespace when a package is being detached".

Comment: hmm.., meaning I need to first understand what is search path and namespace. Let me do that first

Comment: Then you might find this link useful: http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/

Answer (score 9):

[From R's official help pages](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-hooks.html) (see also [R Packages - Namespaces](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#search-path)):

> **Anything needed for the functioning** of the namespace should be handled at load/unload times **by the .onLoad** and .onUnload hooks.
>
> For example, DLLs can be loaded (unless done by a useDynLib directive in the ‘NAMESPACE’ file) and initialized in .onLoad and unloaded in .onUnload.
>
> Use **.onAttach** only for actions that are needed only **when the package becomes visible to the user** (for example a start-up message) or need to be run after the package environment has been created.

- **attaching** and **.onAttach**

  - thus means that a package is attached to the user space
  - aka the global environment
  - usually this is done via `library(pkg)`
  - and you can use normal `fun()` syntax

- **loading** and **.onLoad**

  - thus means that package is (in any way) made available to the current R-session
  - (e.g. by loading/attaching another package that depends on it or by using `pkg::fun()` syntax the first time)
  - though you will not find functions in the global environment
  - you can use `pkg::fun()`

Answer (score 0):

detach related to package environment(which more related to user)
unload = TRUE related to namespace environment(which more related to other package)

after detach, you can not use any function inside that package directly
but unloadnamespace won't prevent you from calling that function,but the other packages can't use its function directly